# How can my application use CPAN modules without the user installing them himself?

Tags: perl, module

I need to use some CPAN modules in my application. If the person who will use my application doesn't like to install the required CPAN modules by himself, or it is not allowed to install modules, how should I handle that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PAR-Packer/lib/PAR/Packer.pm) to create an executable bundle that contains all the CPAN modules your app needs to run.

Comment: The OP could also use pp from PAR::Packer with the -p option to create PAR archives that contain only libraries and have no executable attached.  This option allows the creation of multi-architecture PAR files if desired.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can copy the module's installation to your app's specific directory and include that in @INC.